# Rails dropdown/select location objects with individual params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My scenario is on the home page I want to click a dropdown toggle/select. In that toggle I want it to display a list of `Location` objects. However I want to pass individual `params` that are different in each one. My goal is to use a dropdown to toggle location information in the view. The problem is right now I'm hard coding locations into this drop down. But I am creating `Location` objects on a different page. **I want those `Location` objects to populate the dropdown on the home page, but allow the user's choice to pass params to change the view.** This would allow an unlimited number of locations. What is a good way to accomplish this.

```
index.html.erb

**I erased the dropdown code to simplify things.**

<li><%= link_to "#{@location1}", {:location1 => "location1"}%></li>
<li><%= link_to "#{@location2}", {:location2=> "location2"}%></li>


home_controller.rb

if params[:location1]
   @current_location = Location.last
   @myreviews = Review.where("location_id = ?", @current_location.id).order('created_at asc')
end

if params[:location2]
   @current_location = Location.first
   @myreviews = Review.where("location_id = ?", @current_location.id).order('created_at asc')
  end
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you explain it a bit more. What do you mean by individual params that are different in each one?

Comment: Sure. In the code above inside each link_to has different params like location1 and location2.  each choice effects what location data is shown in the view. Right now I can hard code multiple locations but I want to be able to create an infinite amount Location objects on a location page.... that then supplies the home page the options in a select or loop or something. 

Right now if I do a loop to display an array of all the location objects then the params are repeating so I need differentiate the choices to pass as parms to change view data. Kinda like a params sort. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Here is what I did to solve the problem in the end.

View

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu loc-drop scrollable-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
            <% @locations.each do |u| %>
              <li><%= link_to u.name, :params => {:loc => u.id} %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </ul>
```

Controller

```
   @locations = Location.all
  if params[:loc]
      @chosen_location = Location.where('id = ?', params[:loc]).pluck(:id).first
  end
```

At that point I'm using @chosen_location to display details like name and address.